# Bad error handling of .pdf files against all other file types when a file exceeds the maximum file size

Tags: 7, ajax, files

I have a file field with the following allowed file extensions: `txt, pdf, doc, docx, zip`

The `Maximum upload size` is set via my php.ini  and it is `upload_max_filesize = 2M`

**1.** While I'm trying to upload a file that exceeds the maximum file size I get the following error as expected:

[image]
Any other file (with `file_size < 2MB`) uploaded from before (form submit) remains as is and I have the ability to **re-upload** a new file.

I observed that this is working good with all types of files except one, the `.pdf` type.

**2.** When I upload a `file.pdf` with `file_size > 2MB` I get this error:

[image]

All previous uploaded files (if any - with `file_size < 2MB`) are disappearing (*) and I don't have the ability to re-upload a new file except if I **refresh** the page anew.

The expected behavior would was this (**1.**)  :a warning message telling me about the size of the file and an option to re-upload a file without having to refresh the page anew. Instead I get (**2.**) an error message and no possibility to re-upload any files without refreshing the page.

**Note** that this is the case only for `.pdf` files!

Debugging info:

(*) I found that the responsible function for this behavior is this: [file_ajax_upload](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/file_ajax_upload/7.x)

Its `if()` statement evaluates to true

```
if (empty($_POST['form_build_id']) || $form_build_id != $_POST['form_build_id']) {
    // Invalid request.
    drupal_set_message(t('An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (@size) that this server supports.', array('@size' => format_size(file_upload_max_size()))), 'error');
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  }
```

and the the form's markup is being replaced nicely!

Another more interesting thing that I found through the [chrome's console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), and I believe that it points to the correct direction, is this:

[image]

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
$form['field_name']['#attached'] = array(
  'drupal_add_http_header' => array(
  array('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
);
```

Do you think that this is related to a configuration related to my environment or a bug  ? How can I solve this issue ? Should I go after the `MIME` type somehow ?

Comment: You might want to try setting your max in .htaccess [like in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess)

Comment: Perhaps you mean the `php.ini` file, but the `upload_max_filesize` is not my issue, my issue is the different error handling of the `.pdf` files against all other file types.

Comment: For those who are interested see the related [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2762055) on [DO](https://www.drupal.org/)